# XPath required:Checking values inside Each row of particular column

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a below scenario.I need the xpath for the below:
We have a table with thead Name,Code and Conduct.
Also we or may not have blank column next to code.It may be any number.
But the table Starts with Name and ends with Conduct.

## Thead example:

```
1) <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Name</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Code</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>

2)<Row>
        <Cell><Element>Name</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Code</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>

3) <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Name</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Code</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
```

Tbody's first row should have value in all column.Mainly in Code and Empty thead column.
    Also Cell may contain inner element Element1.

## Tbody First Row example:

```
ex 1) <Row>
        <Cell><Element>abc</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>23</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>

ex 2)<Row>
        <Cell><Element>ttt</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>34</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>45</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>

ex 3) <Row>
        <Cell><Element>yyy</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>22</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>33</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element><Element1>4</Element1>4</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
```

From Row 2 Onwards we need to check at-least any one element in the code column and the adjacent empty column should have value.
If any one row has value then we should convert the table as stated in Sample Output1:(Positive case).
ie) Table name should be changed to XYZ and combile all the element insed cell for Code column and the adjacent empty column.

## Sample Input1:(Positive case)

```
<Table Name="abc">
<Thead>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Name</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Code</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
</Thead>
<Tbody>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Sam</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>1</Element><Element>2</Element><Element>1</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>1</Element><Element></Element><Element>1</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>xyz</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>123</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element><Element></Element><Element><Element1>1<Element1></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
</Tbody>
</Table>
```

## Sample Output1:(Positive case)

```
<Table Name="XYZ">
<Thead>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Name</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Code</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
</Thead>
<Tbody>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Sam</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>121</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>11</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>TTT</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>123</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>1</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>PPP</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>123</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>1</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
</Tbody>
</Table>
```

If all the rows has empty value in any one column then we do nothing.

## Sample Input2:(Negative case)

```
<Table Name="abc">
<Thead>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Name</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Code</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Conduct</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
</Thead>
<Tbody>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>Sam</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>1</Element><Element>2</Element><Element>3</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element><Element></Element><Element></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Element>xyz</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>123</Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element></Element><Element></Element><Element><Element1><Element1></Element></Cell>
        <Cell><Element>Good</Element></Cell>
    </Row>
</Tbody>
</Table>

Sample Output2:(Negative case)
same as input.
```

What we tried:

count(Tbody//Row[count(./Cell[2]/Element[number(normalize-space(.)) and number(normalize-space(.)) > 0]) != 0])

This work for Only Code column but for we dont know how many number of adjucent empty columns will come.For that condition we need to know xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is very difficult to follow, and I am mainly guessing here. Would the following test work for you to distinguish between the two cases?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Table">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Tbody/Row[position() > 1]/Cell[position() > 2 and position() != last()][.//text()]">POSITIVE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NEGATIVE</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What this does is look at every row of the body, starting at row #2, and see if there is a value inside any cell, starting at cell #3 and ending at the cell before the last one. If any such cell is found, the result is positive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As we are using diiffrent component for XSL in our application we used part of your answer which worked. Thanks for your help.